# VBA Excel сложение матриц

Tags: excel, vba, матрицы

Нужно сложить матрицы средствами VBA Excel. Для умножения есть функция листа MMult, для сложения я такую не нашел. Можно складывать поэлементно через циклы For, но для больших матриц в алгоритмах итерации такое сложение без встроенной библиотеки будет очень сильно замедлять расчеты. На сложение матрицы типа C=A+B интерпретатор ругается - несовместимые типы.

Comment: Большие матрицы - насколько большие могут быть? Покажите примеры данных и результата

Answer (score 0):

Зачем поэлементно?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAElTGKlvTM

Если хотите макрос, делайте также как и на видео:

```
Sub Main()
Dim ArrayA As Variant
Dim ArrayB As Variant
Dim ArrayC As Variant
With Range("d6:f8")
 ArrayA = .Value
 ArrayB = .Offset(5,).Value
 ArrayC = .Parent.Evaluate(.Address & "+" & .Offset(5,).Address)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Не очень понял как работает Evaluate, но суд по коду, она работает с данными Range на листе.
У меня данные, которые требуется сложить, получаются в результате промежуточных вычислений
Типа того.
`
b=f.MMult(AtA1, f.MMult(AT, f.Transpose(Y)))
b2 = f.MMult(f.MMult(f.MMult(AtA1, Q), QATAQ1), QTbC)
b=b-b2 'Сложение нужно вот здесь.
`
У меня данные в результате вычислений не Range и командой "+" их похоже не вычислить. Странно, в Excel богатая матричная математика, а сложение не реализовано.

Comment: Ну в этом ничего странного нет, сложение на моей памяти действительно нигде не используется. То есть матрицы - они же созданы для преобразований! Может где-то сложение и нужно, но в тех случаях обычно можно обойтись без матриц.

Comment: Если честно, у меня просто нету установленного Excel. Самую первую версию я написал для OO Spreadsheet / LO Calc, но потом, понял что вы про эксель, а у меня OO, и я попытался побыстрому сконвертировать код без возможности протестировать.